# 16px space at the beginning of website

Tags: html

really strange problem. I got a very basic layout (You can see it here: https://geardev.de/test/test.html), but there is a 16px space above the logo that shouldn't be there.

I have absolutely no idea what would cause this. For your reference: https://geardev.de/test/style.css is the stylesheet, the definitions begin at line 350, before it's only resetting stuff with Normalize.css.

Dismounting the HTML didn't really lead to a result - maybe I'm just missing something stupid. The only thing I noticed was that removing the Doctype is solving the problem - But then it's technically wrong. Btw, it's passing the W3C validator: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fgeardev.de%2Ftest%2Ftest.html

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if you use a web dev tool, you will see that the ul element has a 16px margin on top of it. You set that to zero, you should be good to go.

Comment: Yeah, but where do these 16px come from? I just removed the ul element completely, and the space is back again.

Comment: Now the h2 gets a 16px margin. What the heck?!

Comment: I got it. There's a "-webkit-margin-before" style set in the browser stylesheet. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @afpel nevermind, the edit. And no problem. Glad you have it working now.

Answer (score 0):

This will fix it:
       `<ul style="margin-top: 0px;">`